# Fitting a mixture of two normal distributions for a data set?

Tags: fitting, distributions

EDIT: Raw data can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Kagaratsch/65a931d8d78fcdd81f7e346429a02afd

Consider the following binned example data:

```
hl={{-(153/400), 1}, {-(151/400), 0}, {-(149/400), 0}, {-(147/400), 0}, {-(29/80), 0}, {-(143/400), 0}, {-(141/400), 0}, {-(139/400), 0}, {-(137/400), 0}, {-(27/80), 0}, {-(133/400), 0}, {-(131/400), 0}, {-(129/400), 0}, {-(127/400), 0}, {-(5/16), 0}, {-(123/400), 0}, {-(121/400), 0}, {-(119/400), 0}, {-(117/400), 0}, {-(23/80), 0}, {-(113/400), 1}, {-(111/400), 0}, {-(109/400), 0}, {-(107/400), 0}, {-(21/80), 0}, {-(103/400), 0}, {-(101/400), 0}, {-(99/400), 0}, {-(97/400), 0}, {-(19/80), 0}, {-(93/400), 0}, {-(91/400), 0}, {-(89/400), 0}, {-(87/400), 0}, {-(17/80), 0}, {-(83/400), 3}, {-(81/400), 0}, {-(79/400), 0}, {-(77/400), 1}, {-(3/16), 0}, {-(73/400), 0}, {-(71/400), 1}, {-(69/400), 3}, {-(67/400), 4}, {-(13/80), 4}, {-(63/400), 5}, {-(61/400), 3}, {-(59/400), 2}, {-(57/400), 5}, {-(11/80), 8}, {-(53/400), 4}, {-(51/400), 8}, {-(49/400), 8}, {-(47/400), 11}, {-(9/80), 13}, {-(43/400), 10}, {-(41/400), 11}, {-(39/400), 18}, {-(37/400), 13}, {-(7/80), 21}, {-(33/400), 24}, {-(31/400), 28}, {-(29/400), 18}, {-(27/400), 35}, {-(1/16), 40}, {-(23/400), 39}, {-(21/400), 40}, {-(19/400), 41}, {-(17/400), 45}, {-(3/80), 58}, {-(13/400), 47}, {-(11/400), 59}, {-(9/400), 55}, {-(7/400), 71}, {-(1/80), 85}, {-(3/400), 70}, {-(1/400), 65}, {1/400, 83}, {3/400, 85}, {1/80, 83}, {7/400, 68}, {9/400, 73}, {11/400, 66}, {13/400, 61}, {3/80, 70}, {17/400, 60}, {19/400, 63}, {21/400, 48}, {23/400, 52}, {1/16, 46}, {27/400, 34}, {29/400, 43}, {31/400, 36}, {33/400, 27}, {7/80, 21}, {37/400, 23}, {39/400, 13}, {41/400, 17}, {43/400, 26}, {9/80, 9}, {47/400, 15}, {49/400, 6}, {51/400, 7}, {53/400, 5}, {11/80, 5}, {57/400, 8}, {59/400, 2}, {61/400, 2}, {63/400, 4}, {13/80, 2}, {67/400, 4}, {69/400, 3}, {71/400, 3}, {73/400, 5}, {3/16, 1}, {77/400, 3}, {79/400, 0}, {81/400, 3}, {83/400, 1}, {17/80, 1}, {87/400, 0}, {89/400, 1}, {91/400, 0}, {93/400, 5}, {19/80, 0}, {97/400, 1}, {99/400, 1}, {101/400, 0}, {103/400, 0}, {21/80, 1}, {107/400, 0}, {109/400, 0}, {111/400, 0}, {113/400, 0}, {23/80, 2}, {117/400, 0}, {119/400, 1}, {121/400, 0}, {123/400, 0}, {5/16, 0}, {127/400, 0}, {129/400, 0}, {131/400, 1}, {133/400, 0}, {27/80, 1}, {137/400, 0}, {139/400, 0}, {141/400, 0}, {143/400, 0}, {29/80, 0}, {147/400, 0}, {149/400, 0}, {151/400, 0}, {153/400, 0}, {31/80, 0}, {157/400, 0}, {159/400, 0}, {161/400, 0}, {163/400, 0}, {33/80, 0}, {167/400, 0}, {169/400, 0}, {171/400, 0}, {173/400, 0}, {7/16, 0}, {177/400, 0}, {179/400, 0}, {181/400, 1}, {183/400, 1}, {37/80, 0}, {187/400, 0}, {189/400, 0}, {191/400, 0}, {193/400, 0}, {39/80, 0}, {197/400, 0}, {199/400, 0}, {201/400, 0}, {203/400, 0}, {41/80, 1}};
ListLinePlot[hl]
```

> [image]

I would like to fit a sum of two normal distributions into this data, so I try

```
mod = NonlinearModelFit[hl, A1 Exp[-A2 (x - A3)^2] + B1 Exp[-B2 (x - B3)^2], {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3}, x] // Normal;
```

Mathematica complains that there are convergence issues, and sure enough a plot of the result is very unsatisfactory:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[hl, PlotRange -> All], Plot[mod, {x, -0.3, 0.3}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

> [image]

What is the proper way to do this fit in Mathematica, so that it actually converges to a sensible approximation?

**EDIT**

Interestingly, comparing the (normalized) naive fit to the mixture and smooth kernel distributions from the answer by [JimB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200846/5517) we see that the fit deviates from the distributions quite a bit

```
Show[Plot[PDF[mixture /. sol, z], {z, -0.4, 0.4}], 
 Plot[mod, {x, -0.4, 0.4}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[SKD, {x, -0.4, 0.4}, PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Do you have frequency counts or does the data consist of pairs of measurements?  If the former, then `NonlinearModelFit` is inappropriate. 
 If the latter note that the model (a mixture of two curves with a similar shape as a normal distribution) assumes equal variability across all values which the data does not exhibit.  There's much less variability in the tails than in the middle.

Comment: @JimB Those are frequency counts. Right, so my question is - how to fit a sum of two Gaussians into a distorted bell curve? I don't have any strong attachment to the `NonlinearModelFit` function. Please, let me know if there is a better function for the job?

Comment: @TeM Amazing, you are right! That is very curious...

Comment: @TeM Kagaratsch is fitting a mixture distribution based on a random sample.  That is NOT a regression.  `NonlinearModelFit` is inappropriate for that situation.  (Just because one can do it, doesn't one should.)  Typically one uses maximum likelihood approach with raw data.  But here the data has either been collected in bins or was binned.  If the raw data measurements were available, that would make things simpler (but one can fit a mixture model with binned data).

Comment: @JimB I only have shown binned data here for simplicity. In fact, I do have access to the raw data. It would be great if you could describe how I should proceed with that?

Comment: OK.  If there's too much raw data to add, I'll make up some data to show how to fit a mixture of normals.

Comment: @JimB Thank you, I'm looking forward to it! I just put the raw data here: https://gist.github.com/Kagaratsch/65a931d8d78fcdd81f7e346429a02afd

Comment: And to be picky:  you have a "mixture" of normal densities (which is a weighted sum of the densities) rather than a "sum" of two normal random variables.  You might want to change "sum" in the title to "mixture".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Statistics is more than mathematics.  One needs to account for how the data was collected rather than just starting with the data and applying some analysis procedure.

What you have is a random sample from a distribution that you've hypothesized to be a mixture of two normal distributions.  (The initial attempt at using regression is a common misconception that seems to be prevalent in this forum.  I have to believe that this approach must be (inappropriately) used in subject matter textbooks because it seems to occur so often.)

Using the `data` you provided it is relatively simple in *Mathematica* to fit a mixture of normal distributions:

```
mixture = MixtureDistribution[{w1, 1 - w1},
  {NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2]}]

sol = FindDistributionParameters[data, mixture]
(* {w1 -> 0.964246, μ1 -> 0.00764751, σ1 -> 0.0853816, μ2 -> 0.208146, σ2 -> 0.189363} *)
Plot[PDF[mixture /. sol, z], {z, Min[data], Max[data]}]
```

[image: Mixture distribution]

Unfortunately `FindDistributionParameters` does not supply standard errors or covariance among the parameter estimators.  But that is not too difficult either.

```
(* Log of the likelihood *)
logL = LogLikelihood[mixture, data];

(* Parameter covariance matrix *)
cov = -Inverse[(D[logL, {{w1, μ1, σ1, μ2, σ2}, 2}]) /. sol];

(* Standard errors *)
se = Thread[{sew1, seμ1, seσ1, seμ2, seσ2} -> Diagonal[cov]^0.5]
(* {sew1 -> 0.013437142118899128`,seμ1 -> 0.0021502023883548864`,
    seσ1 -> 0.0018001069575776648`,seμ2 -> 0.05745078807898059`,
    seσ2 -> 0.022206958940369257`} *)
```

**Addition**

While the resulting probability density estimate might still look like a single "normal" here's a comparison of the mixture distribution, single normal fit, and a nonparametric density fit.

```
Plot[{PDF[NormalDistribution[Mean[data], StandardDeviation[data]], z],
   PDF[mixture /. sol, z],
  PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], z]}, {z, Min[data], Max[data]},
 PlotLegends -> {"Normal distribution", "Mixture of 2 normals", 
   "Smooth kernel distribution"}]
```

[image: Smooth kernel, mixture, and single normal estimated densities]

Comment: Let's just say that I knew of the hammer called `NonlinearModelFit` and so the problem looked a lot like a nail to me. :)

Comment: Good way of putting it.  (We all have analogous hammers.)  You are not alone concerning `NonlinearModelFit`.